# How to measure dwell time on emails

Tags: email, html-email, measurement

I'm working on an email based experience. One of the things we'd like to measure is our users' engagement in the form of dwell time (time from opening the email until closing it). 
In order to get our open rate we added a small image to it and so when the email is opened we get a request to retrieve it and are able to count that.
So far we didn't come up with a solution we could use in order to measure the entire time the user spends reading our emails...
Is there a standard way of doing that? or some "trick" we could use?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Litmus (paid service) can get you those results.